# Task execution role for ECS tasks - Cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam, amazon-ecs

I am trying to access an IAM role which I created using aws console. The role was simple as I had to give in ecs taskexcutionrole so that it has the permission to pull the image from ECR. I have come up with this code what am I missing in this code?

```
    Role:
        Type: 'AWS::IAM::Role'
        Properties:
          AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
            Version: '2012-10-17'
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Principal:
                  Service:
                    - ec2.amazonaws.com
                Action:
                  - 'sts:AssumeRole'
          Path: /
          ManagedPolicyArns:
            - arn:aws:iam::02004621356:role/ecs-ec2-task
```

2- What if I want to create a new task execution role and give only permission to pull the image from ECR what changes I should make?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The trust principle [should](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-iam-roles.html#create_task_iam_policy_and_role) be `ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com`:

```
Role:
    Type: 'AWS::IAM::Role'
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com
            Action:
              - 'sts:AssumeRole'
      Path: /
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - arn:aws:iam::02004621356:role/ecs-ec2-task
      Policies: 
        - PolicyName: AccessECR
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: 2012-10-17
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Action: 
                  - ecr:BatchGetImage
                  - ecr:GetAuthorizationToken
                  - ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer 
                Resource: '*'
```

Comment: Thanks Marcin, what about the second part of the question? Please help

Comment: @Shifa Anser updated. But easier would be to just use AWS managed policy: `arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonECSTaskExecutionRolePolicy`.

Comment: The arn you mentioned in the comment is already built and you are just using it, right?

Comment: @Shifa Yes. Its provided by AWS. You can got to IAM console, policies and search for it by name. And check what it contains.

Comment: @Shifa No problem. Let me know how it will go and if need some adjustments to the role.